# Load arrays into recordset to loop through to increment value vba access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to load values from two tables of an access database (in the same database file as the VBA code) into arrays to loop through and increment the value in EQP_POS_CD field when the PART FIND NO matches the previous PART FIND NO. The query:

```
SELECT CTOL.ID, CTOL.BOM_PART_NAME, CTOL.CII, CTOL.[PART FIND NO], CTOL.CSN,
       CTOL.AFS, CTOL.EQP_POS_CD, CTOL.LCN, CTOL.POS_CT, CTOL.SERIAL_NO, 
       CTOL.PART_NO_LLP, [CTOL_Asbuilt].[PART-SN], [CTOL_Asbuilt].[PART-ATA-NO], 
       [CTOL_Asbuilt].[PW-PART-NO]
FROM CTOL LEFT JOIN [CTOL_Asbuilt] ON CTOL.[PART FIND NO] = [CTOL_Asbuilt].[PART-ATA-NO];
```

Code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit




'Const adOpenStatic = 3
'Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Function queryDatabase()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef
'Dim rsQuery As DAO.Recordset
Dim rows As Variant


Dim part_find_no() As String
Dim eqp_pos_no() As Integer
'Dim strSQL As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
'Set objConnection = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CTOL")

Set db = CurrentDb

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("SicrProcess")

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

If rs.EOF Then GoTo Leave
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst


For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount
    part_find_no() = rs("PART FIND NO")
    eqp_pos_no() = rs("EQP_POS_CD")
    If part_find_no(i) = part_find_no(i - 1) Then
        eqp_pos_no(i) = eqp_pos_no(i) + 1
    End If
    Debug.Print rs.Fields("PART FIND NO") & " " & rs.Fields("EQP_POS_CD")
    rs.MoveNext
Next i

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    db.Close
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. It's expecting arrays, but do I have to initialize those arrays somehow? How would I set those fields to an array from the results generated by the query? I want the arrays to be loaded with the results from that query but just those fields: PART FIND NO and EQP_POS_CD. Then it should loop through the rows in the two fields to increment EQP_POS_CD when the current PART FIND NO is the same as the previous PART FIND NO. Any advice on how to clean this up? Thanks.

Comment: Have to declare an array with dimensions. If the number of elements are not know in advance then will have to ReDim the array. Review http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm

Comment: You should use SQLfor this and is much faster. if you still want to use VBA at least you should add "order by" clause in your sql so that your vba logic would work. Except that, you don't need array just use two variables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think array objects are needed. Consider:

```
Sub SetSeq()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, x As Integer, strPart As String, intSeq As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Part Find No], EQP_POS_CD FROM CTOL ORDER BY [Part Find No], SERIAL_NO;")

If rs.EOF Then GoTo Leave

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
strPart = rs![Part Find No]
For x = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    If rs![Part Find No] <> strPart Then
        intSeq = 0
        strPart = rs![Part Find No]
    End If
    intSeq = intSeq + 1
    rs.Edit
    rs!EQP_POS_CD = intSeq
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Next x

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

The table after running code:

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+
| EQP_POS_CD | Part Find No | SERIAL_NO |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|          1 | a            | abc1      |
|          2 | a            | abc2      |
|          3 | a            | abc3      |
|          1 | b            | abc4      |
|          2 | b            | abc5      |
|          1 | c            | abc6      |
|          2 | c            | abc7      |
|          3 | c            | abc8      |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This looks pretty good! I'll test it out. I'm still getting familiar with VBA, but how do you call a sub in a VBA module? I've been looking around for how to call a VBA sub within a module, but I'm confused. I put a call underneath the Sub and it throws an error saying that only comments can follow End Sub. Thanks again!:)

Comment: Never mind, I'll just try running it as a function from a macro (does that work?). I'm getting the following error now: "Invalid use of Null". I'm trying to find out where this Null value is. Any ideas?

Comment: The code triggering it is:

strPart = rs![PART FIND NO]

Comment: Update: Noticed a null value in the dataset. I modified the query to exclude null values. Saw in another question post that a string value in VBA cannot be null. However, now I'm trying to run the function from the macro RunCode and it's doing nothing. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Another update: I've found the code directly affects the table itself. Now, I realize I need a way to reset the first value of each PART FIND NO to be 1, as running the VBA code just keeps incrementing the value.

Comment: Isn't saving to table what you wanted? I tested this code on a table and it resets the increment for each distinct PART FIND NO. A procedure can be called from within another procedure, such as a button Click event. A Sub can be manually executed with the Run button on the VBA editor menu. Just make sure the cursor is positioned anywhere within the sub code. Did you ever get the suggestion in your other question to use DCount() in query to work? Did you try using RunningSum property of textbox in report? Do you plan to run this code every time new records are added? Do you ever delete records?

Comment: It's okay that it updates the table. I don't have any forms or reports yet. I got the suggestion from you on DCount(), but it didn't work for me. I got a syntax error. The problem I'm having is the EQP_POS_CD calculation is not accurate. I'm going to look at the code to make sure there isn't an error in the logic (which isn't reported, though there may be a way to). I've made it this far with the VBA code, and I feel I'm getting closer to getting it to work. So I want to stick with that method for now. There's going to be more work to be done with it to accommodate new records as well soon.

Comment: But I want to get this function to work first before diving into further territory. Take it step by step. The function runs, so that doesn't appear to be the issue right now.

Comment: I'm not sure why we're getting different results though. Could you post the results you're getting? Maybe I'll just re-import the data and try the code again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay, I edited answer to display table after running code. Perhaps you should post example of your data.